# Locking object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking, devexpress

Hi all I am having a code where user can select a record from gridview and make payment, now I guess of a situation if multiple users select the same record at a time and proceed to the payment then the record get updated with the amount paid, so in order to avoid this situation i thought of locking in c#, will this work in my situation

```
protected void buttonclick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   if(grid.SelectedRow!=null)
   {
     lock(grid.SelectedRow)
     {
        // my code
     } 
   }
}
```

In live environment will this lock that row until the operation was completed, or should I choose other

Comment: This won't work. Handle it from the database. What database platform are you using?

Comment: reading material for concurrency control in MSSQL Server 2008  http://codepalace.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-concurrency-control-in.html @Learner

Comment: The 'lock' you're using is for multithreading purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Different people will be looking at different screens with different instances of the grid view on them. So no, locking a row in the UI will not help you. This can be solved in the database.

See for example [optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one..

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/274545/record-locking-using-csharp-net

and

[How to perform a row lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767328/how-to-perform-a-row-lock)

These may help.