# Lock a row in a table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking

I need to lock a row in a table so no one can read this line while I'm running a procedure. I am using `BEGIN TRAN` in this procedure. So, this record I'm trying to block is uncommitted during the process.
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible Repeat Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111652/locking-row-in-sql-2005-2008

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is the purpose of your stored procedure:

**- In case it modifies the mentioned row, you can base on [transaction levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)**

> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
>
> BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> --UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE your row here
>
> ...
>
> COMMIT TRANSACTION
> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

**- Use [lock hints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)**

> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
>
> BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> SELECT column1, column2
>
> FROM *yourTable* WITH (ROWLOCK)
>
> WHERE ID = *YourRecordId*
>
> ...
>
> COMMIT TRANSACTION
>
> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ